# How to solve AttributeError when importing igraph?

Tags: python, import, package, igraph

When I import the igraph package in my project, I get an AttributeError. This only happens in the project directory:

```
[12:34][~]$ python2
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Apr 15 2011, 12:09:10) 
[GCC 4.5.2 20110127 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import igraph
>>> 

[12:34][~]$ cd projectdir/
[12:34][projectdir]$ python2
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Apr 15 2011, 12:09:10) 
[GCC 4.5.2 20110127 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 36, in <module>
    class GzipFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
>>>
```

There is no file igraph.py in the project directory:

```
[12:34][projectdir]$ ls -alR | grep igraph | wc -l
0
```

And there are no circular imports.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Most likely, there is a module `io` in `~/projectdir` or one of the paths the project configures. The gzip module imported by igraph starts with

```
import io
```

and expect the built-in io module, not your project's one. Look for an `io` directory, or `io.py` or `io.pyc`. It can also help to scrutinize `sys.path` for any other directories (maybe outside of `~/projectdir`) that might contain modules named `io`.

Comment: Thanks. I had a package `io` in my project. Next time I know how to solve this.

Comment: So that's the cause... what's the resolution? It seems that the obvious solution is to rename the `io` package in the project, but is the there another solution that doesn't require renaming the io package?

Comment: @mutzmatron Leaving your custom `io` is a recipe for trouble, so you should really rename it. While you *can* temporarily modify `sys.path`, that's incredibly brittle. In any case, you should use absolute imports, like `import myproject.div.io_utils`

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @phihag - though it's a little annoying that import statements don't respect hierarchical namespaces properly - or I guess more accurately that when a package's directory is added to the path, it makes any of it's functions or submodules importable without specifying the full hierarchical namespace.