# Python gzip fails on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, gzip

The function below based on the Python sample code in [the Python gzip module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html). It runs reliably on Ubuntu 10.04 with its default Python 2.6.x. On Ubuntu 11.04, however, the code fails @ `writelines()`.

On one 11.04 machine, the failure message reported `'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'`. Another 11.04 machine reported a different message `No module named numpy`. Yet, the numpy package is installed on both machines.

Does anyone know of any missing Python dependencies or other problems on 11.04 that would cause this?

```
def _compress(inp,out):
    import gzip
    f_out = gzip.open(out,'wb')
    f_in = open(inp,'rb')
    f_out.writelines(f_in)
    f_out.close()
    f_in.close()
    os.unlink(inp)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve AttributeError when importing igraph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315440/how-to-solve-attributeerror-when-importing-igraph)

Comment: What does `numpy` have to do with `gzip`? You're probably looking for you error in wrong place.

Comment: Have you got an `io.py` file, or an `io/__init__.py` around that might be getting imported?

Comment: I saw the igraph discussion. It's not the same because this code throws the error on writelines(), not on "import". Also, there are no other io.py (et.al.) in the sys.path. I sent the update to the user with the huge data files and I'm waiting for him to report if the code below fixed the problem.

Comment: I stand corrected. There was a competing file named io.py in the sys.path. Renaming that file solved the problem. However, also leaving the io.py there and running the code change to eliminate writelines() ALSO solves the problem. Interestingly, this problem does not occur on 10.04 or 10.10 (both Python 2.6x). Either deleting io.py or avoiding the writelines() or both solves the problem. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `No module named numpy` is unrelated to this problem; some other bug is causing this. To track this down, print the value of `sys.path` to see which paths Python would search for a module. Numpy might be installed but maybe not in a place included in `sys.path`. That out of the way, back to your main issue.

1. Check the Python version. My guess is that 11.04 comes with 2.7.x.
2. `writelines()` is an odd method to call for binary data. Even worse, the parameter should be a sequence of strings, not a file object. Try this code instead:

   ```
   f_out.write( f_in.read() )
   ```
3. Depending on the file size, this eats a lot of memory. Try a loop instead:

   ```
   while True:
       data = f_in.read( 10240 )
       if not data: break
       f_out.write( data )
   ```

Comment: yes, 11.04 is running Python 2.7x. Thank you for suggesting the loop. These text files are quite huge. I'll try your alternative. Tom

Comment: This solved the problem, as did removing the unnecessary io.py in the sys.path. Doing both also runs fine. Thanks.