# class GzipFile(io.BufferedIOBase): AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase' installing python tables

Tags: python-2.7

I have a problem while installing python tables.
There is something missing or corrupt in my path or dependencies that I can not solve.

When I'm using a Python program that uses tables, it returns:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/io.py", line 331, in 
    def bget(imfile,shp=None,unpackstr=N.int16,bytesperpixel=2.0,sliceinit=0):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'int16'
```

And simply importing tables from python shell:

```
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 36, in 
class GzipFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

tables is installed in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

My PYTHONPATH is:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bbfreeze-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/altgraph-0.9-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phylonetwork-1.0b6-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables-3.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

What am I missing?

Any healp would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 4):

Facing the same issue, I found this interesting answer : [How to solve AttributeError when importing igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315440/how-to-solve-attributeerror-when-importing-igraph)

You should check for packages names `io` and 'N' in your own sources.
Make sure they do not overlap definition of `io` builtin packages and numpy (you seemed to have imported `as N`)

Renaming them solved this issue for me.

Comment: What a wicked problem. I have a project with an `io` module name that has been working but stopped tonight with this error. Renaming it to something other than `io` immediately resolved it. Thanks for posting this.