# Got Error when using the Cython.Build in Python

Tags: python, gzip, cython

When I import the Cython.Build, It give me the error like this

```
  >>> from Cython.Build import cythonize 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Dependencies import cythonize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 10, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 36, in <module>
    class GzipFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

I try to reinstall the Cython but seems useless. How can i solve it ? Thankyou !

Comment: Looks like a compatibility issue (https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/505). May be it works in python3

Comment: Do you have a file named `io.py` in your current directory, or a subdirectory called `io`? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6315440/1426065

Comment: It is very amazing that the error has gone after I am using the import io !  Btw thankyou for you help!